# How to remove rows based on row values and columnn values in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with room service details as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Trade":["003K", "003M1", "003M2", "003M1", "003M2", "003M1", "004K", "004M1", "004M1", "010M2", "010M1", "014K", "014M1", "014M2", "023K", "023M2"],
             "Room":["abc18", "abc18", "abc18", "abc10", "abc10", "abc10", "abc67", "abc67", "abc79", "abc32", "abc34", "abc1", "abc1", "abc1", "abc4", "abc4"],
             "Number":[99,99,99,85,85,59,26,26,26,92,56,38,38,38,67,67],
             "Open":["C", "C", "C", "G", "G", "G", "K", "K", "K", "RK", "T", "D", "D", "D", "J", "J"],
             "Exit":["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "R", "R", "R", "HT", "M", "J", "J", "J", "K", "K"]})
```

It looks as follows: df

```
    Trade   Room    Number  Open    Exit
0   003K    abc18   99      C       A
1   003M1   abc18   99      C       A
2   003M2   abc18   99      C       A
3   003M1   abc10   85      G       A
4   003M2   abc10   85      G       A
5   003M1   abc10   59      G       A
6   004K    abc67   26      K       R
7   004M1   abc67   26      K       R
8   004M1   abc79   26      K       R
9   010M2   abc32   92      RK      HT
10  010M1   abc34   56      T       M
11  014K    abc1    38      D       J
12  014M1   abc1    38      D       J
13  014M2   abc1    38      D       J
14  023K    abc4    67      J       K
15  023M2   abc4    67      J       K
```

I want to remove when column containing specific `K` ID matches with `M1 or M2` or both in terms of other columns. i.e. if all the columns matches with the for the specific id remove it. The expected output is:

```
    Trade   Room    Number  Open    Exit
0   003M1   abc10   85      G       A
1   003M2   abc10   85      G       A
2   003M1   abc10   59      G       A
3   004M1   abc79   26      K       R
4   010M2   abc32   92      RK      HT
5   010M1   abc34   56      T       M
```

Comment: Why is the 3rd Row kept when Number(59) doesnot match

Comment: @DareDevil This question looks almost similar to the recently asked question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67134821/how-to-extract-dataframe-by-row-values-by-conditions-with-other-columns. Is this a coincidence?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma I am not sure about the question that you have posted. May be a coincidence.

Comment: @anky that is what is required. The non matching rows are required. If M1 or M2 has a match with K considering all other columns will be removed

Comment: ya.. almost... but requires small changes